# adjective + wh-

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, adjectives, sentence-usage

> Be careful whom you hire.

There is an example in Oxord advanced learner’s dictionary.
**careful when/what/how, etc.**
I wonder if the sentence I mentioned above is part of the usage of the *adjective + wh-*.

Comment: The adjective here licenses an interrogative content clause as core complement. And yes it is part of the usage you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "Does that sentence conform to the usage mentioned in OALD **careful when/what/how**? - yes, it does.

It should be *[Be] careful whom* **you** *hire*, and, although *whom* is strictly correct for the object case, most people would say *Be careful who you hire.*